# Access to folders that require root

Tags: rooting, root-access, data-recovery

I'm trying to find my deleted notes in xiaomi phone(i'm still hope :( ) since May. But i coulndt done it yet with adb. Therefore i'm going to do last decision:''Rooting my phone to access folders'' But i dont know that will files gonna delete after root my phone. Are they deleted or not. A man named Andrew said to me that no documents delete completely. I really thanks to him i hope so thats why i'm trying since May. I really want my notes back. Would d2d transfer would help or is root my last chance i want to know thank you.

Comment: Rooting your phone usually requires unlocking your bootloader which will execute a factory reset. A factory will delete everything including your encryption required for decryption all your user data, so without that key data recovery absolutely impossible.

Comment: @Robert so there is nothing we can do?

Comment: @Robert I remember you said something about d2d transfer few months ago. If i need a  device which is rooted, i can transfer all the data without root my phone?

Comment: Assuming the app uses a database file for storing the notes (and the db file also includes the deleted notes) and the app does not disallow backup, migrating the phone via USB to a new rooted device could work.

Comment: @robert Does that new device need big memory and miui ? Because my phone has miui

Comment: Your question is very general, therefore you get answers like one from Rohan. You should have linked your old question about [adb backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/251888/2241) and which mentions the path where the files are located, because knowing the path eliminates the possibility to recover data from a different app.

Comment: Regarding device2device transfer: As the notes app is AFAIK a xiaomi  system app I would say you need another xiaomi device with a compatible notes app. The USB based transfer as I know it is only available if the target phone has been factory reset. But the whole process is often a bit intransparent, so you never know what data is copied and which not (and why). But I never had the case of moving a system app, so I can not help you with real experience...

Comment: Sp you're saying i cannot know without try yep?

Comment: @Robert i bought a new xiaomi phone (it's miui version is lower than mine btw) but Xiaomi doesnt have d2d app. Do you have suggest for app

Comment: Normally you don't need a special app. First you complete the initial set-up wizard. On some devices this wizard has a possibility to take-over data from a previous device via USB. If not then some time later a notification should appear to "complete device set-up" in that you should have the option for USB transfer. Use an USB-C cable and directly connect phones and hope for the best.

Comment: @Robert Thanks man if it works i really dont know how to thank you and some people in here. Same if it wont work i dont care you guys always helping me.